# undefined offset in array PHP

Tags: php, curl

i normally use my online web-server for web development, but for some reasons i needed to test it in my XAMPP locally.

my code below will fetch images from a website via curl, and display the total images fetch.

what baffles me, im getting this error on XAMPP:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 15 in C:\Web\xampp\htdocs\curl\fetch.php on line 69
```

line code 69: is `if($images_array[$i]) {` below

```
    <?php
    $image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';
    preg_match_all($image_regex, $html, $img, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    $images_array = $img[1];
    ?>

    <div class="images">

    <?php
    $k=1;
    for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($images_array);$i++) {
        if($images_array[$i]) {
            if(strstr($images_array[$i],'http')) {
            echo "<img src='".$images_array[$i]."' width='100' id='".$k."' >";
            $k++;
            } 
        }
     }
     ?>

    <input type="hidden" name="total_images" id="total_images" value="<?php echo --$k?>" />

    </div>
```

i have no problems using this code in my online webserver. i imported all my files from my webserver to XAMPP with no changes made with it. also, my curl is enabled by checking `phpinfo()`

i hope someone could point whats making this `undefined offset` error.

Comment: check `var_dump($images_array)` or `print_r($images_array)` to see what is inside `$images_array`.

Comment: You probably don't have any problems using it on your local server either. Read the message, it's not an error, it's a **notice**. Just differences in the PHP's `error_reporting` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `<= sizeof($array)`:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($images_array); $i++) {
```

`sizeof()/count()` return the number of entries. Since array indices start with 0, you must either use `$i <= count($arr) - 1` or use `$i < count($arr)`.

Error reporting is probably turned off in your production environment, therefore you don't see the notice.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the

```
if($images_array[$i]) {
```

use this:

```
if(isset($images_array[$i])) {
```

And also use this:

```
$i< sizeof($images_array)
```

or `$i < count($images_array)`

instead of `$i<=sizeof($images_array)`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<=` from `for ($i=0;$i<=sizeof($images_array);$i++)`

Since `$i` is starting from 0

Answer (score 0):

change `<=` in your `for` into just `<`

Because if the `sizeof($images_array)` is for example 5 , `$images_array[5]` will not exist.

Only 0 ... 4 (5 in total).

By changing `<=` in your for into `<`, you will prevent accessing `$images_array[5]` and thus prevent the notice from being shown.